# Blazor Server with OpenIdConnect fails when trying to sign out

Tags: .net, authentication, openid-connect, blazor-server-side, .net-7.0

I have a Blazor Server in .NET 7 set up to use OpenIdConnect to authenticate/authorize users using *Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect* (7.0.12). I've done it like this.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddServerSideBlazor();

    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        // I've tried this
        options.DefaultScheme = "MyScheme",
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc"

        // and this, but never both at the same time
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "MyScheme";
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = "MyScheme";
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "MyScheme";
    })
    .AddCookie("MyScheme")
    .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
    {
        // My OIDC options 
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
        endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
    });
}
```

I sign in using `await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync("oidc");` in a login.cshtml file I've linked to in my menu. This works just fine. I get the "MyScheme"-related cookies and Blazor understands that I'm signed in.

This all falls apart when I'm trying to logout. The logout process also happens through a cshtml file I've linked to in my menu. Inside this I run `await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("oidc");` and `await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("MyScheme")`. When I run the application the first time, this actually works. If I log in, stop the application, start it again, and then try to log out I get an `ObjectDisposedException` when calling `SignOutAsync("oidc")` saying:

> IFeatureCollection has been disposed

Why am I getting this exception and what can I do to prevent it?